# Attempt at writing a proof of non-existence of Conway’s 99-graph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Here is my attempt at proving that a graph satisfying the conditions of Conway's 99-graph problem doesn't exist:

[image]

[image]

Is my reasoning valid? If so, what can I improve to make the proof more understandable?

Comment: Please try to post self-contained questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown that $Z$ is a $12$-regular graph on $84$ vertices. Why would it be strongly regular?

Any vertex in $Z$ has $12$ neighbors in $Z$. And any vertex in $Z$ is adjacent with two vertices in $Y$. Therefore, by The Pigeon Hole principle, there exist $z_1,z_2\in V(Z)$ and $y\in V(Y)$ such that $y,z_1,z_2$ are all adjacent (a triangle).

Therefore $z_1,z_2$ have no common neighbors in $Z$, and $Z$ is not $\textrm{srg}(84,12,1,2)$.